# How to find if date is contained in a set of intervals?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL v13.

I need to find if a specific timestamp is included in a set of intervals. And of course, my idea is to do it in a single query instead of looping and building multiple queries.

So this query basically needs to merge the following statements for `n` intervals: `<date> BETWEEN <start> AND <end>`

Example of what I want (not a valid SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM rides r
WHERE device_id = 1 
AND timestamp IN (
       SELECT tstzrange(start_at, end_at)
       FROM segments 
       WHERE device_id = r.device_id
);
```

But of course the IN operator does not work that way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `EXISTS` and [range functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-range.html)

```
SELECT * FROM rides r
WHERE device_id = 1 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM segments 
       WHERE device_id = r.device_id 
       AND tstzrange(start_at, end_at) @> r.timestamp ::timestamp );
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems I missed that operator... There are thousands of functions and operators with infinite possible combinations. Mindfuck.

Comment: yeah, there are a lot if them, but the manual is good structued.